# How do I tell which binary XML file is causing an error in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I decompiled an .apk for an input method which I'm trying to change the on-screen layout for. My desired changes succeeded on Nexus 10, but my Nexus 4 crashed with the following error in logcat. How do I tell *which* exact .xml file is causing the error? There are literally hundreds of .xml files all spaghetti-referencing each other.

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344): java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #5: You must     supply a layout_width attribute.
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5819)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5988)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1831)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1743)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:757)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at gp.a(SourceFile:82)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.libs.framework.keyboard.KeyboardViewHelper.a(SourceFile:144)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.libs.framework.keyboard.Keyboard.getBodyView(SourceFile:154)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.libs.framework.keyboard.KeyboardSnapshotTaker.a(SourceFile:173)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.libs.framework.keyboard.Dashboard.onKeyboardReady(SourceFile:160)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.libs.framework.core.InputBundle.a(SourceFile:33)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at dO.onKeyboardDefReady(SourceFile:224)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at ed.a(SourceFile:84)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at ed.onPostExecute(SourceFile:65)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5344):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You have THAT many xml files to not being able to take a look at recently opened XMLs at the line 5? (just a question)

Comment: as in log `line #5: You must supply a layout_width attribute.` means you forget to add layout_width attribute in xml for any view

Comment: Yes, there are hundreds of .xml files. This is Google's Chinese Pinyin IME which has all kinds of bells and whistles. (The change I'm trying is small -- I just want the in-built QWERTY layout changed to Dvorak. I had to edit several files for this to work because it has separate landscape/portrait layouts, separate english/chinese layouts, etc. After all my changes, it works perfectly on my Nexus 10 but my Nexus 4 crashes.) Is there really not a way for it to tell me which file is the source of the error?

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't seem to catch it. 383 errors and 2202 warnings in Google's code I didn't even modify but nothing related to missing layout_width ...

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure lint should catch such errors. You can use it either as a command line tool or from Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't seem to catch it. 383 errors and 2202 warnings in Google's code I didn't even modify but nothing related to missing layout_width ...